# org-mode inline images not working (remotely with TRAMP)

Tags: matplotlib, emacs, jupyter, org-mode, tramp

I am working with emacs org-mode on a remote machine using TRAMP. I connect code cells to a jupyter server (on that remote machine) where I start a python 3 kernel. Code execution works perfectly fine, I can also create plots with matplotlib. While a .png is generated in the right temp file location, the output of the code cell is a (relative) link to the file without displaying it inline as expected.

An example code-block look like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-python :session /jpy:localhost#9090:TEST
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), range(10))
#+END_SRC
```

```
#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
| <matplotlib.lines.Line2D | at | 0x7f1c43a289a0> |
[[file:./.ob-jupyter/e1eecf5d59de9bfa1d3468867a64aadf4b1a6261.png]]
:END:
```

`C-c C-x C-v` gives the message: `'No images to display inline'`

`C-c o` opens and displays the file in a different buffer correctly.

I would expect the file to display correctly inline in the org-mode buffer.

I tried to change the link manually to a TRAMP path, looking something like this:

```
[[file:/ssh:MYSERVER:/PATH_TO_TEMP_FOLDER/.ob-jupyter/e1eecf5d59de9bfa1d3468867a64aadf4b1a6261.png]]
```

which also allows me to open the file with `C-c o`, but won't display the file inline (Same behavior as described above)

If I open the jupyter-repl session directly and type `fig` (after executing the above code block) The figure displays as expected in the jupyter-repl buffer

If I run the jupyter session locally, inline plotting works as expected

---

### Update:

I realized if I `C-f` on the link to open the file, the link expands to an invalid tramp link, which throws the following error message:

```
File is missing: /ssh:bih:/PATH_TO_CORRECT_FOLDER/00_test/file:./.ob-jupyter/
```

Note the `file:./` at the end of the link that doesn't belong there. So I think something is going wrong somewhere between TRAMP and org-mode (or emacs-jupyter). Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-h v org-display-remote-inline-images` says:

```
org-display-remote-inline-images is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is ‘skip’

How to display remote inline images.
Possible values of this option are:

skip        Don’t display remote images.
download    Always download and display remote images.
cache       Display remote images, and open them in separate buffers
            for caching.  Silently update the image buffer when a file
            change is detected.
```

Check the value and maybe customize the variable to do something other than `skip`.

Comment: Fantastic that was it - thank you so much Nick!